# Using generating function determine $u_n$

Tags: generating-functions

Using generating function determine $u_n$
$$u_{n+2}+8u_{n+1}-9u_n=8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^n$$
$$u_0 =2 $$
$$u_1 = -6$$
And my attempt:
$$u(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0} u_nx^n$$
$$u_{n+2}+8u_{n+1}-9u_n=8 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^n$$
 $$\sum^\infty_{n=0} u_{n+2}x^{n} + 8 \sum^\infty_{n=0} u_nx^{n-1} - 9u(x) = 24 \frac{1}{1-3x}$$
After transformations:
$$u(x) = \frac{\frac{24x^2}{1-3x} +10x +2}{1+8x-9x^2}$$
And I don't know it is good solution and how to finish it.
If it is bad, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote the first term on the LHS as $\frac{u(x) - u_0 - u_1 x }{x^2}$ and the second as $ \frac{8(u(x) -u_0)}{x}$ and then did the algebra, that should be fine. Don't forget expand the fraction on the RHS.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: you have a typo in the second term on the LHS: it should be $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} u_{k+1}x^k$

Comment: What exactly is you complication? What do you get?

Comment: $\frac{u(x)−u_0−u_1x}{x^2}+ 8\frac{(u(x)−u_0)}{x} - 9u(x) = 24 \frac{1}{1-3x}$

Comment: Note $1+8z -9 z^2 = (1-z)(1+9z) = \phi_1$, so on the RHS you'll have $\frac{24}{(1-3z) \phi_1}$- split it in three, the other ones $\frac{a_0}{\phi_1} +\frac{a_1 z}{\phi_1} + \frac{8 a_0 z}{\phi_1}$, which are elementary